# A4Tech mouse not working

Tags: mouse

I connected a new mouse via USB to my netbook with Ubuntu and it does not work (but the mouse laser is ON). Here's what `dmesg` says:

```
[   39.747822] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci-hcd
[   39.768627] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=09da, idProduct=000a
[   39.768698] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   39.768761] usb 3-1: Product: USB Mouse
[   39.768805] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: A4Tech
[   39.778492] usb 3-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
```

What should I do to make it working?

Comment: Have you tried to plug it into other USB ports?

Comment: i have problem when i plug A4tech mouse in usb 3 .. try in USB 2 work fine

Comment: I tried to connect it via second USB port but with no success...

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the module `hid-a4tech` loaded. Run `sudo modprobe hid-a4tech`, and check whether it's working.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I got: "Module hid_a4tech not found." (Ubuntu changes `-` to `_` itself).

Comment: The extra kernel modules are missing, run the following in a terminal: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-generic`

Comment: `Package 'linux-generic' has no installation candidate` PS. I'm using Chrubuntu on Samsung Chromebook (ARM).